# Intelliji Idea does not see folders on Fedora system

Tags: java, linux, intellij-idea, fedora

photo file explorer -(https://i.stack.imgur.com/poxoV.png)
photo ide -[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EHsSv.png)

Intelliji Idea does not see folders on a Fedora system. I suspect it's a matter of permissions, but how do I give them to the program?

I was thinking of trying to add the JDK folder to environment variables and retrieve it that way

Comment: I'm trying to open the jvm folder where the jdk is located

Comment: Please try to run IDE with sudo rights. Will it help?

Comment: This question seems to be about Linux system administration, not programming. Unfortunately I could not find the right button to flag this post.